# Strange results when removing rows with negative values

Tags: r

I was performing some simple subsetting on my data when I tried to remove all rows with a negative value.

Example code:

```
df1 <- df1[df1$var2 >= 0,]
```

In my current dataset this action should remove four rows. However, no rows are removed after executing.

Strangely, the following code does only leaves those four rows that should be removed by the first code:

```
 df1 <- df1[df1$var2 < 0,]
```

I found that using `subset(df1, var2 >= 0)` does work and removes the four rows that I want to have removed. But I always thought that the first code was the same as using `subset()`? Does someone know why the very first code doesn't work the way I intend it to?

Edit, including some data from my dataset:

```
> dput(df1[1:10,215:220])
structure(list(KBUY_CER = c(3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 
2L), KBUY_PRO = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), KBUY_DEF = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), THINK_SP = c(NA, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA), dwifexp = c(NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 0L, 0L, NA), dwifdoll = c(NA, 1500L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 600L, 600L, NA)), row.names = c("389", "390", "391", "392", 
"393", "394", "395", "396", "397", "398"), class = "data.frame")
```

All columns I've selected data from work as intented, only column 215 (`KBUY_CER`) seems to have this problem.

I just found out that the four rows that should be removed are actually not negative but `NA` values, which explains why both `[`'s don't remove those rows from the selection. But does `subset()` always remove `NA` values then?

Comment: Difficult to tell without a reproducible example but that could happen if you have floating point values in `var2`. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Is `var2` numeric? Are you resetting `df1` after running these lines that modify it? Please share some data reproducibly, like `dput(df1[1:10, ])`.

Comment: Thanks, and then subset avoids the problem with floating point values @RonakShah?

Comment: No - `subset` and `[` behave exactly the same regarding floating point values... and floating point issues generally come about when comparing to decimal numbers, comparisons with 0 should be just fine. I doubt it's relevant here. What would help a lot is a reproducible example with some sample data, e.g., `dput(df1[1:10, ])`. Then we can really see what's going on.

Comment: @GregorThomas I edited my original post with a part of the dataset. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, the `[` and `subset` behavior is different for missing values. When you put `NA` inside `[`, the result is `NA` a row of `NA`s. Many people use `which` with `[` to make it behave like subset, e.g.,  `df1[which(df1$THINK_SP > 0), ]`